# Prettier Pragma Support in non JS files

Tags: javascript, code-cleanup, prettier

Adding `"requirePragma": true`, to the prettier config makes it format a files that contain a special comment only.

Here is a special comment for *.js* and similar files, according to the [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html):

```
/**
 * @prettier
 */
```

or

```
/**
 * @format
 */
```

How to make such a comment in files, such as *.html* or *.json*, where comments of this kind are not allowed?

For example `<!-- @prettier -->` is not recognised as a special comment in *.html* files

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ending up here in the future:

This appears to be partially solved today, but not for all formats.

- .md gets `<!-- @format -->`
- .html gets `<!-- @format -->`
- .yml gets `# @format`

JSON still doesn't get anything, which makes sense.

The documentation doesn't mention this explicitly: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#require-pragma